# Do rails has loading fixture function like django-extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to load some dummy data for test local development. How can I make it like [django-script](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html) or django's fixture?

Comment: yes, with better implementation. have a look up to `rake tasks`

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Built-In_Rails_Tools/Make_your_own_rake_tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you can run `rake db:seed` to seed the database. The command uses  `db/seeds.rb` under the hood - this is the file you need to edit. It can be used both to seed production (e.g. create pre-defined categories in an e-commerce store) and development (e.g. create some products for testing purposes only).

I recommend that you separate production and development seeds like this:
create a directory `db/seeds` and change `db/seeds.rb` to:

```
case
when Rails.env.production? then load 'db/seeds/production.rb'
when Rails.env.development? then load 'db/seeds/development.rb'
end
```

Then put the database initialization code in both `db/seeds/production.rb` and `db/seeds/development.rb`. You can normally use your models from both these files.